How to use sonar.exclusions for Delphi applications
I am trying to use SonarScanner on some Delphi 10.3 applications. I am using the sonar-delphi plugin to perform the analysis. It worked perfectly on small applications, but in more complex applications, it throws some errors on certain files that don't make much sense. I tried using sonar.exclusions to ignore the files with errors, but it's not working; it keeps throwing errors on the same files even after adding them as excluded.
Here is an example of my sonar.properties:
# Sources
sonar.sources=.
sonar.language=delphi
sonar.delphi.libraryDirectories="C:/Program Files (x86)/Embarcadero/Studio/20.0/source"

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

# Exclusions
sonar.exclusions=file1.pas,file2.pas,file3.pas

Keep in mind that all the files are in the root of my project
I also tried adding it directly in the command line where I invoke Sonar with -D"sonar.exclusions" but it didn't work.
